# Angular and NGXS store application ends in a loop through store update

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I use NGXS as store mechanism. In the store there is a list of conditions, these are displayed in the `RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionComponent` via `*ngFor` on the UI. So each condition gets its own `RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionListCardComponent`.

Each condition contains settings such as SelectTargetType. These settings are each implemented in an extra component e.g. in `RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionListCardSelectTargetTypeComponent`. If the user now changes the setting, this setting is changed and saved via dispatch in the store. By changing the StoreModel, the *ngFor is again triggered by the Observable which also triggers the `ngOnInit`  which leads to a loop with the following error. How can I change the settings so that the list is updated but no errors are thrown?

[image]

**RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionComponent**

```
<div *ngFor="let condition of (conditions$ | async)">
  <app-rule-engine-add-view-stepper-condition-list-card [conditionId]="condition.conditionId">
  </app-rule-engine-add-view-stepper-condition-list-card>
</div>

export class RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionComponent {
  ...
  @Select(RuleEngineState.getConditions)
  public conditions$: Observable<RuleCondition[]>;
  ...
}
```

**RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionListCardComponent**

```
<app-rule-engine-add-view-stepper-condition-list-card-select-target-type [conditionId]="conditionId">
</app-rule-engine-add-view-stepper-condition-list-card-select-target-type>
```

**RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionListCardSelectTargetTypeComponent**

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="form">
  ...
</mat-form-field>

export class RuleEngineAddViewStepperConditionListCardSelectTargetTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ruleId = this.store.selectSnapshot(RuleEngineState.getSelectedRuleId);
  }

  private onFormChanges(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
       const targetType: RuleConditionTargetType = val.targetType;
       if (targetType) {
         this.store.dispatch(new RuleEngineConditionAddTargetTypeAction(this.ruleId, this.conditionId, targetType));
       }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a useful solution. I used TrackBy to prevent rendering the complete list, now I only render the elements that are newly added.

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-trackby-with-ngfor-in-angular-8